# How to get list rows and column values

Tags: c#

So I am currently trying to convert some of my old C++ code into C# for practice purposes, in my C++ I have the following lines of code:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list)
{

    numCol = (*(list.begin())).size();
    numRow = list.size();
    /...More Code
}
```

The i_list is typedefed as follows: `typedef initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> i_list;`

As we can see it is a 2D List, in my C#  code I have done something similar however I defined the list signature in the parameters of my constructor since according to my understanding C# lacks typedefs as follows:

```
MatrixLogic(ref List<List<Object>> matrixList)
        {

        }
```

However I am at a lost as to how to properly fetch the number of columns and number of rows for the matrixList. The format it will be entered in will be as follows: `myEntry = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}` or some variant of that.

Comment: Well for one a `List<List<double>>` is not necessarily square like a Matrix` is.  The closest structure would be a `double[,]`.

Comment: Also you can do something similar to typedefs:
using MatrixList = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>>;

Comment: Use reflection - `Object o; o.GetType().GetProperties.Count()` to figure out total number of columns

Comment: Also, C# is not at _extension_ of C++; there are many constructs in C++ that do not exist in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, a `List<List<double>>` is not *necessarily* square like a `Matrix` is.  The closest built-in structure in C# would be a `double[,]`.

That said, if you *assume* that all elements of the outer list are the same size, then the length of the "outer" dimension would be

```
matrixList.Count
```

and you could look at the size of the first item to get the "inner" length:

```
matrixList[0].Count
```

Comment: Gotcha. So let us say someone were to do a 4 by 2 list as follows: {{1,1},{1,1},{1,1},{1,1}} would this still fall under outer list being same size?

Comment: And a quick follow up, I assume this would only work with arrays and not lists correct? As lists do not have a Length functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - in a `List<List<>>` there's no way to _enforce_ that all items be the same size, so you could have  `{{1,2},{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4}}` as well.  Arrays have fixed sizes but are less dynamic (you have to specify the size when creating them).

Comment: Sorry, it's `Count` not `Length`.

Comment: Gotcha, no biggie, one quick final question; how would one go about declaring it statically. Trying to do it as {{1,2}, ... } appears to not be allowed. Of course this is just a case of having to learn more about the differences of C# and C++, but I was wondering if you know how to do it, looking for 2d lists I see it a lot of things about doing some sort of key-value pair, but I do not believe this is what I require.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) on initializers or [do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+initialize+list) - there's lots of examples out there.  Note that each inner list needs to be initialized (`{new List<double> { ...}, new List<double> {...}, ...}`).  If the size is static then arrays are easier to initialize.